# AMP(Accelerated Mobile Page) form development in AEM 6.1

Tags: java, aem, amp-html, aem-6, amp-form

I am trying to develop a AMP form in AEM 6.1 and trying to submit data to back end sling servlet to save the data into database.But I am getting error in return:

```
<body>
<form class="sample-form"
  method="post"
  action-xhr="/bin/rating.rest"
  target="_top">
  <input type="text"
    name="name"
    placeholder="Name..."
    required>
  <input type="email"
    name="email"
    placeholder="Email..."
    required>
      <input type="text"
    name="title"
    placeholder="Title..."
    required>
    <input type="textarea"
    name="textarea"
    placeholder="Feedback..."
    required>

     <fieldset class="rating">
      <input name="rating" type="radio" id="rating5" value="5" on="change:rating.submit">
      <label for="rating5" title="5 stars">☆</label>

      <input name="rating" type="radio" id="rating4" value="4" on="change:rating.submit">
      <label for="rating4" title="4 stars">☆</label>

      <input name="rating" type="radio" id="rating3" value="3" on="change:rating.submit" checked="checked">
      <label for="rating3" title="3 stars">☆</label>

      <input name="rating" type="radio" id="rating2" value="2" on="change:rating.submit" >
      <label for="rating2" title="2 stars">☆</label>

      <input name="rating" type="radio" id="rating1" value="1" on="change:rating.submit">
      <label for="rating1" title="1 stars">☆</label>
    </fieldset>
      <input type="submit"
    value="Submit Feedback">
  <div submit-success>
    <template type="amp-mustache">
      Success! Thanks {{name}} for trying the <code>amp-form</code> demo! Try to insert the word "error" as a name input in the form to see how <code>amp-form</code> handles errors.
    </template>
  </div>
  <div submit-error>
    <template type="amp-mustache">
      Error! Thanks {{name}} for trying the <code>amp-form</code> demo with an error response.
    </template>
  </div>
</form>
</body>
```

Back End Code::::

```
@SlingServlet(paths="/bin/rating.rest", methods = "POST", metatype=true)
```

public class AmpRatingActionServlet extends SlingAllMethodsServlet {

```
    protected void doPost(SlingHttpServletRequest request,SlingHttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException,
        IOException {

    String jsonData = null;
    String name;
    String email;
    String title;
    String textarea;
    String rating;
    try
    {
    name = request.getParameter("name");
    email = request.getParameter("email");
    title = request.getParameter("title");
    textarea = request.getParameter("textarea");
    rating = request.getParameter("rating");
    log.info(CLASSNAME+"::Inside Try Block:::::::name::::"+name+":::::email:::::"+email+":::::title:::::"+title+":::::textarea:::::"+textarea+":::::rating:::::"+rating);
    }
            }catch(Exception e) {
      log.error(Error occurred in Servlet", e);
   }
}
```

500
Message 
javax.jcr.nodetype.ConstraintViolationException: No matching property definition: name = Test

Comment: Please provide minimal, complete and verifiable example, see https://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/.

Comment: This typically happens when your servlet is not registered properly in OSGi, due to which the control goes to the default POST servlet which tries to save the create the data submitted as nodes and properties in CRX. Taking a quick look at the AmpRatingActionServlet, the class shouldn't compile due to an extra closing curly brace before the catch statement.

Comment: The servlet class is compiled and deployed in AEM.I am facing issue during the servlet call.Error:::::500 Message javax.jcr.nodetype.ConstraintViolationException: No matching property definition: name = Test

Comment: Check your Components tab and services tab in OSGi to see if your servlet is active and is not in a resolved or inactive state. Also use the resource resolver functionality in OSGi console to see if the servlet URL resolves to your Servlet Class.